# how to prevent stealing javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I made many javascripts for my blogger after hard work. So, I don't want anyone steal my codes, can I do that?
I tried obfuscate and encode from many websites, but anyone can easily steal it after that, So it just slow my website.
I need **really** solution : )

Comment: Obfuscation is the best you can do. Javascript runs on the client, so they have to be able to download it.

Comment: if you're asking this, i promise you no one wants to steal your code.

Comment: Due to the very nature of the web, this is impossible.  The client must be able to download your code to run it, and you can only do so much to mangle the code and still be valid JavaScript.

Comment: No! Obfuscation is bad solution

Comment: my code is very important, and I know it will be stealed. is there any method or free server run the scripts and send its values?

Comment: It's too late, I've already stolen your code and sold it for a billion dollars.

Comment: @ZiyadZadi No offense, but your lack of understanding what JS is, and the implications of that, the difference between serverside and clientside code, the possibilieties to lazy-load JS, ... this question - all that suggests that your code won't be that sophisticated, and therefore valueable to be stolen; if you just raise the obstacles a bit. There are more than enough free and well documented sources for almost any JS-problem, so I don't have to bother to de-obfuscate the code of a Newbie.

Comment: OK. thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The only thing you can do is make your code harder to read by minimizing it, and otherwise obfuscating it. The code is sent to the client; you must assume they'll try to read it.

If you visit a website and the page is already "constructed", it means they used a server side language/framework to create the page before it was sent.

Comment: I saw websites doesn't show there javascripts, just show the texts. I think it is use servers.

Comment: @ZiyadZadi That means they're using a server side language to construct the page instead of sending the code. You can only do that for code that creates the page, not code that reacts to events.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are shown publicly, and sent directly to the client, so there's no way you can prevent them from being viewed. You had the right idea trying to obfuscate it, as that's the only solution, you just need to find the right obfuscater. In my opinion, you shouldn't even obfuscate them, as most scripts are written in a matter of minutes, it wouldn't make much sense for somebody to steal yours. If you really need to do so, then a quick google search returns [this](https://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. At the end of the day, the user can look at any javascript that is being run on the client. If you're doing anything that is business sensitive (such as connecting to databases, etc), that should take place on the server, so that users can't see it. Client-side JavaScript is intended to work with data that the user can see anyway, so it's not important for it to be obfuscated.

If you're just jealous that someone is going to to use your code, well.. Tough luck. Though I should say that in all likelihood nobody is interested in stealing your code. If they're going to reuse code, they'll download a plugin - not go through the source of random websites to see if there's anything they could scavenge.

People have mentioned obfuscation, but if that's your goal, you're doing something wrong. You should certainly minify your code - but that's to make it take less space, and thus load faster. Not to obfuscate it.

Comment: Some claim 'it's harder to read, therefore obfuscating it' but there's always pretty print